# Can I salvage this out of focus image?

Tags: lens, focus

I took this photo with Canon EOS 1200D, using the 55–250mm kit lens. Unfortunately the pic is out of focus. Is there anything I can do to salvage this or fix the focus?

[image: Koodiyattam tradition]

Comment: related : https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/47284/sharpen-blurred-photo

Comment: related : https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/37697/how-can-i-fix-an-out-of-focus-blurred-photo-in-photoshop

Answer (score 0):

To be blunt,

A shot that is out of focus will always be out of focus. It will always be **a bit off**.

You can try to add some sharpening but that will heavily decrease the overall quality of the image. I would not bother with trying to save this image, beautiful as it may be..

Comment: How does [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/37706/15871) to [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/37697/15871), including an example that was improved significantly, fit with your answer here?

Comment: I stand by my claim that a photo that is out of focus will never look **good**