# How can I fix an out of focus photo? Is there an app for that? I don't have Photoshop

Tags: post-processing, focus, blur

Someone else took this picture of me and didn't focus. :(

How can I fix this? Is there an app for that? I don't have Photoshop.

[image: blurred image]

Comment: Except, this one specifically says "I don't have Photoshop."

Comment: We've also got the same previous question for GIMP and other applications.

Comment: Keep in mind that photo editing is not magic. If it were possible to perfectly re-focus an out-of-focus image, nobody would bother to focus in the first place.

Comment: [How can slightly blurred photos be improved in post processing?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/4724/15871)

Comment: [sharpen blurred photo](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/47284/15871).

Comment: @mattdm The accepted answer to the "photoshop" question uses a non-Photoshop based solution (to very great effect, I must say).

Answer (score 5):

You can't make it perfect, but there's an algorithm with the fancy name "Richardson–Lucy deconvolution" which can get impressive results.

The open source and free software program [G'Mic](https://gmic.eu/) has a feature to do this. It's implemented as a plugin for GIMP. You can find it in the "Details" section of the G'MIC plugin, which is under the Filters menu.

[image: gmic]

Play around with the sliders. "Sigma" is the most important; it basically corresponds to how big the blur circles are. Somewhere around 4 seemed to work for this image. I ran it with 100 iterations; this makes more speckling but has a stronger sharpening effect, too.

The image is also significantly unfderexposed — probably the camera was fooled by those bright lights in the backround — so I used a quick shadows & highlight adjustment too. You could also play around with those manually to get things better, but this is a quick fix. The resulting image has some speckling and other artifacts; I think for a final result you'd want to do some by-hand touchup. But this should get you started.

[image: edited in gmic]

Comment: @scottbb Replaced with a version done in G'MIC, which allows much more extreme adjustment.

Comment: Could it be an idea to add the original reference to Rawtherapee? Reading the original answer I was wondering whether it was also possible with RT, until I looked at the answer's history

Comment: @clabacchio I could. I switched it to G'Mic because this particular image needs a value higher than the (I think arbitrary, although I haven't dug into the code to see) scale limit in Rawtherapee.