# Sentimental photo taken by an iPhone out of focus

Tags: focus, iphone

First let me say I am not a photographer, however I have a photo that was taken of my mom, myself and niece that is very dear to me.  The photo was not properly focused I don't think.  Could a professional improve the focus?  I would love to enlarge and frame it.

Comment: Hi Robin, welcome to Photo.SE. Without seeing the photo to see how badly out of focus it is, your question is unfortunately unclear. If you upload the photo, we could possibly help you better. I understand that perhaps you might not want to upload the photo for privacy reasons. If that's the case, I will link to some existing questions  to give you an idea of what can be done to try to fix focus after the fact.

Comment: Related: [How can I fix an out of focus photo?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/92194/11924), [How can I fix an out-of-focus blurred photo in Photoshop?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/37697/11924), [sharpen blurred photo](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/47284/11924)

Answer (score -2):

Professional photographers can do wonders, though the skill level in photoshop varies fairly widely among the group. Finding one with the right skill set will be your challenge.

That being said, photographers typically stop right after manipulation - they don’t typically add things that weren’t there. In your out of focus shot, you have details missing due to the focus.

A graphic artist may be able to take things a step further by adding back those lost details.

This better be one heck of a sentimental photo though, because either option above is going to cost a bit.